# Loading current updated code in broswer

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, internet-explorer, page-refresh

is there any trick how to get every single time current updated code in browser while refreshing? I tried to use cache killer extension in chrome but doesn't help either. 
I tried to use all tricks I know to get fresh data like shift+F5, ctrl+F5, ctrl+R and it doesn't helps as I need. If I save my code and wait like 1 minute then it loads new code but if I would like to see changes immediately then it works like 3 out of 10 times instantly but mostly is it just denying to give me what I want.
Any ideas please? :)

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What code is not updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is [Browser-sync](https://browsersync.io/).

After downloading it, navigate to the specified folder using the terminal and hit the following command:

```
 C:\Users\..\..\..>browser-sync start --server --directory --files "*"
```

In case my instructions are not understood, the website will definitely be more explanatory.

Comment: Cheers for your reply, I'll use that.

Answer (score -1):

Hi dear use this in chrome

chrome://settings/clearBrowserData [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du5SX.png)

go to history and settings in all browsers and clear all cache it will works

Comment: Cheers for your reply, however this is not really time saving :)